# How to change output of Jasper REST API to JSON instead of XML

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am planning to integrate a jasper report in my grails application. The report is already available in my community edition server. I have looked into the Web Service API. But it always return XML output. For example, if I call this webservice,

```
http://localhost:8181/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources?type=inputControl&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=password
```

I get following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<resources>
    <resourceLookup>
        <creationDate>2015-08-26T12:27:31</creationDate>
        <description></description>
        <label>locationIds</label>
        <permissionMask>1</permissionMask>
        <updateDate>2016-02-09T13:47:42</updateDate>
        <uri>/tusar/inputControl/locationIds</uri>
        <version>1</version>
        <resourceType>inputControl</resourceType>
    </resourceLookup>
<resourceLookup>
```

My intention is to get the output in JSON instead of XML.

Answer (score 1):

You have to supply the content type header along with the request, so that the jasperserver can response with requested format.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8181/jasperserver/rest_v2/resources?type=inputControl&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=password
```

Comment: Accept with application/json worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add json tags for all the elements inside the jrxml template.For that you need to right click on the report element and -- >json tag -->Json Metadata Path and click ok.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="ID"/>
```

the above property will be applied to the element after that
 so you can access the json data using the URL

```
http://localhost:8181/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/samples/samplereport.json&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=password
```